# Waiting for .ready and button click before function

Tags: javascript

My Google map only shows if function `a` is `document.ready`. However, then the function `dothis()` is called before the user clicks a button which calls function `getMyID(inputId)`.

How do I run my script when the document is ready and a button is clicked?

Here's my code:

```
 function dothis(inputId)
 {
 if (inputId == "1"){
dlat=30.745271;
dlng=0.578793;
getLocation();
}
else if (inputId == "2"){
dlat=40.836671;
dlng=0.578793;
currentloc();
}
```

}

```
 $(document).ready(function a() {

 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ALsbSyEQvVel4MCu9xMBvD_92qAuqrFrcnos0dc&libraries=geometry,places&sensor=true&callback=dothis';;
 document.body.appendChild(script);
```

};

```
$(document).ready(function() { a(); })
```

Comment: I have edited my code a little and it showing an empty map as my current code is not waiting for a user click before doing the dothis function therefore instantly calling currentloc().  Is there a way I can wait till user clicks?

Answer (score 0):

Well, why not call a() like

```
$(document).ready(function() { a(); })
```

Or if you don't use jquery, then

```
window.onload = a();
```

OnLoad works a bit differently though: it doesn't wait for the resources to load (e.g. images) to fire the event. jQuery document-ready event will wait for all the resources to load and then fires the event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery, try it this way :

```
function dothis() {
...
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#MyButton').click(dothis);

}
```

This way, the button will be associated to the dothis function which can be called once the document is ready ;)

Comment: Op is calling for a JS answer, not a jQuery answer!

Comment: I know, I was only suggesting an answer in case if he wanted to have a look at jQuery. Otherwise, he may be interested in ``document.onload``, but people already answered it before I posted the comment.

Comment: Please have a look at the section jQuery of 'The Many Memes of SO': http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/223278

Comment: Well, thanks for the tip, I'm not quite used to SO for instance :)

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is to call window.onload and initialize you button click handler there
eg

`function dothis() { 
    // Do this
}`

`function getInput(input) { 
    // Get input
}`

`function init() { 
    document.getElementById('mybutton').onclick = getInput
}`

`window.onload = init`